# How to show all records from one table even if they don't match WHERE clause with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a problem with a consult im trying to achieve :

```
SELECT [columns] FROM table1 LEFT/RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.id_user = table2.id  [WHERE clause] GROUP BY column
```

An example of what I want this consult to do is shown below:

Having this records in table1 :

> id | id_user |   user  | value
>
> 1 |         1          | name1 | 10
>
> 2 |         1          | name1 | 10
>
> 3 |         1          | name1 | 11
>
> 4 |         1          | name1 | 10
>
> 5 |         2          | name2 | 11
>
> 6 |         2          | name2 | 11

And this ones in table 2:

> id | user
>
> 1 | name1
>
> 2 | name2

I would like to get how many records exist of every user given a value, for exmample if we look for value 10 I would like to get :

> name1 | 3
>
> name2 | 0

I've tried with LEFT and RIGHT JOIN but didn't work, I just got this as are the only records that match the WHERE clause i guess:

> name1 | 3

And not result for name2.

I've been unsuccessfully looking for a solution before taking my problem here, hope someone can help me with this issue :)

Sorry for the bad english.
I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: id_user values in table 1 do not match with id column in table 2. Why id_user of name2 are 1 instead of 2?

Comment: sorry that was my bad, just fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the most efficient query but this should work

```
select user, (select count(*) from table1 b where b.id_user=a.id and b.value=10)
from table2 a
```

often, because this query is so inefficient, i will join the results on the client instead of trying to do it in sql.  the process would go something like this.

1. select * from table2
2. select id_user, count(*) from table1 where value=10
3. iterate through query #1 and store the results in an object that might look like `{'user': name, 'count': 0}`
4. iterate through query #2 and update the  objects from step #3.

it always depends on the size of the result sets and maybe hardware involved, but often this has been faster albeit quite a bit more complex to write in the code.

Comment: Just tried this solution and it works as I want to. Thank you! I'll try to do the join on client side also

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT t2.user,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.id=t1.id_user THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalRecords 
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.id =t1.id_user
GROUP BY t2.id 
HAVING t1.value=10
```

Comment: tried this but gave me the same result, just the records for name1, my actual query is this: 
SELECT t2.queue AS "Queue", SUM(CASE WHEN t2.id=t1.id_queue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalRecords
FROM queues t2
LEFT JOIN calls t1 ON t2.id = t1.id_queue
WHERE t1.datetime_end BETWEEN '2013-02-21 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-21 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY t2.queue